Binding redirects are not working for one project
As the title states I have one project where it appears that our binding redirects are not being applied. We are currently using Visual Studio 2017 for our TFS build sever but we are developing in VS2022.
I am using the below binding redirect but fuslog is showing that the binding is not being considered.
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces"                 
     publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>`

Fuslog
    The operation failed.
    Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.
    
    Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Running under executable     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.exe
    --- A detailed error log follows. 
    
    === Pre-bind state information ===
    LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
     (Fully-specified)
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
    LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
    LOG: Cache Base = NULL
    LOG: AppName = Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.exe
    Calling assembly : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.32.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60.
    
    LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.

WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\config\\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Src/Main/Projects/Conduent.Infrastructure/bin/x64/Debug/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file:         C:\\Src\\Main\\Projects\\Conduent.Infrastructure\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=9.0.0.0,          Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL   file:///C:/Src/Main/Projects/Conduent.Infrastructure/bin/x64/Debug/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL    file:///C:/Src/Main/Projects/Conduent.Infrastructure/bin/x64/Debug/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL   file:///C:/Src/Main/Projects/Conduent.Infrastructure/bin/x64/Debug/Microsoft.Bcl.Async            Interfaces/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
We are at the max version for EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.32.0 that we can go to.
I have tried downgrading and upgrading Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces. Downgrading only gets an error for Microsoft.Threading.Extensions.Tasks with the same issue.

I have gone through all  .csproj, app.confg and packages.config files. Only one csproj had an old version referenced. Still getting the same error. There is no reference to Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterface 1.0.0.0 in any project. Clean/rebuild, delete .vs folder.
